# how to fix bootstrap not working in php file in layout/index.php while using modularity technique?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am currently learning to make a web using php and using modularity techniques. Previously I managed to run bootstrap on a php file. but when I create a folder in my directory with the name 'layout' and then in the layout folder, i make new php file with the name 'index.php' for the web display, and I give bootstrap with stylesheet in layout/index.php, it turns out bootstrap doesn't work.

[Take a look in my directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6xmB.png)

and Here's my index.php

```html
<?php

$modul =isset($_GET['modul'])?$_GET['modul']:'default';

$action = isset($_GET['action'])?$_GET['action']:'index';

include 'layout/index.php';
?>
```

and here's layout/index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MAIN MENU</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, intial-scale=1">
        <style>
            body {
                text-align: center;
            }
            section{
                background-color: white;
                margin: 25px 0px;
                padding: 25px;
                border: solid black;
                border-radius: 25px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="jumbotron text-center text-light bg-danger" style="margin-bottom: 5px">
        <h1>PHP <br> TEKNIK MODULASI FILE DAN DIREKTORI</h1>
    </div>
</header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-danger navbar-dark justify-content-center">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php?modul=menu1">Kalkulator</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php?modul=menu2">Menu2</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php?modul=menu3">Menu3</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php?modul=menu4">Menu4</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php?modul=mahasiswa">Mahasiswa</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section class="container">
    <article>
        <!--- ini adalah content--->
        <?php

        include 'modul/'.$modul.'/'.$action.'.php';

        ?>
    </article>
</section>

    <footer class="py-5 bg-danger">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; 2019 Imam Faried Helmi</p>
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

[Here's the result, bootstrap is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHtRW.png)

when i take this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">
```

into index.php the bootstrap is work. but why bootstrap not working in layout/index.php ?

Does anyone know how to fix it? Help me please :)

Comment: Where is the Javascript part? You need to run the JS files of JQuery and Bootstrap.

Comment: When look at your webpage in the inspector, does your styles get loaded ? The link to your css files depends on where you have placed them and how you accese them. Try this inside your layout folder:
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen">`

Comment: I don't use javascript here. but using javascript or not, the bootstrap still doesn't appear

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I don't use javascript here. but using javascript or not, the bootstrap still doesn't appear

Comment: Time to look at your [developer tools](https://updraftplus.com/faqs/how-do-i-open-my-browsers-developer-tools/), they are very handy in situations like this. You can see what gets loaded, any errors that might occur, etc.

Comment: @FloriandeVille i'm using internal css, and i tried it but still bootstrap not working

Comment: @KIKOSoftware when i look at developer tools, it show this message **GET http://localhost/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)** whats the meaning of this ? i already link bootstrap directory without warning but in developer tools i get that message.

Comment: That must be the reason it doesn't work. Can you go to the other index.html, which has the same file but working? Go to the html source code there, and click on the link to the bootstrap CSS file. Now you should see that CSS and have the URL in the address bar of your browser. Use that URL in your new index.html. This should be an absolute URL, instead of a relative URL.

Comment: Alternatively, use the original bootstrap link: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware well it's work with original bootstrap link, but why local bootstrap not work? that's very strange

Comment: Because the link to the local bootstrap file is not right. See my longer suggestion on how to get it right.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware but in my text editor (I use phpStorm), the code for linking local bootstrap does not display an error warning. so i think bootstrap is ready for use, but it turns out bootstrap doesn't work.

Comment: If it can break, it will... but you found the problem, so I'm sure you can solve it.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware well, thanks for your help bro :) i hope i can solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
```

This will work for sure. As you have not added bootstrap.min.css please check first.

Comment: I see your local url, just try this href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"  if not working then please share console log screenshot from inspect element.

Comment: Finally it's working bro. but in my text editor (I use phpStorm), the code for linking local bootstrap display a warning(cannot resolve directory bootstrap). is okay to let it be? although there is no warning on the console from inspect element.

Comment: Cheers! You can ignore that warning.